# Tomcat Apache 7.0: How to change appbase and docbase in server.xml

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I'm very new for using tomcat apache 7.0.
I have installed tomcat as located in : C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0

And this is my web application located: D:/Document/clientproject/src/main/webapp

I have changed the server.xml of tomcat as following:

```
<Host name="www.tmpclientapp.com" appBase="???" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"> 
   <Context docBase="???" path="" reloadable="true" source="???"/> 
  </Host>
```

I don't know what I should change in appBase and docBase and also source.

Please help me.

Comment: appBase is Your Default Application Base directory and docBase Path to ur application

Answer (score 0):

why you want to change appBase and docbase any specific reason ?

default appBase is webapps folder.
and docBase is you application folder.

if you want to deploy your application on /  create a war with name ROOT